# A question on root system projected down orthogonally onto a subspace

Tags: combinatorics, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

A reduced root system $\Delta$ on a finite dimensional Euclidean space $V$ is called a normal  $\sigma$-system of roots if $\exists$ a linear involutive isometry  $\sigma:V\to V$ such that $\sigma\Delta=\Delta$ and $\sigma \alpha-\alpha\notin \Delta$ $\forall \alpha\in \Delta$.

Let $V=V^{+}\oplus V^{-}$ be the orthogonal decomposition of $V$ into corresponding eigenspaces of $\sigma$.Now my question is the following.

If I look at the orthogonal projection of all elements of $\Delta$ onto $V^{+}$ such that projections are non-zero,then would that collection of projections also form a root system (not necessarily reduced) inside $V^+$?

If the answer is positive then is there any quick way to verify that?

Relevance of this question: I have been studying the classification of  real simple lie algebras where understanding some specific kind of involution(like mentioned in the question) of the root  system of the complexified lie algebra becomes important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is true if you replace the condition by $\sigma\alpha + \alpha \not\in \Delta$ (as can be seen in Lemma 3.3 of Oshima & Sekiguchi's "The Restricted Root System of a Semisimple Symmetric Pair", but is probably somewhere in Knapp's book as well). I'm not sure if changing the $+$ to a $-$ changes the answer.

Comment: Isn't that the content of Prop. 2.1 in [Araki's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-13/issue-1/On-root-systems-and-an-infinitesimal-classification-of-irreducible-symmetric/ojm/1353055009.full) from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4629007/96384)?

Comment: Anyway, it is an interesting question. I think Schattschneider's [On restricted roots of semi-simple algebraic groups](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jmath1948/21/1/21_1_94/_pdf) (J. Math. Soc. Japan Vol. 21, No. 1, 1969) and Heck's [Involutive automorphisms of root systems](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/research/art/involutions.pdf) (J. Math. Soc. Japan Vol. 36, No. 4, 1984) are probably highly related papers dealing with this kind of questions.